# php script works in shell, but not on webserver

Tags: php, webserver, file-permissions, fuseki, arc2

My php-script works perfectly, if I execute it in a shell (`$ php test.php`). But if I call the same php-file in my web-browser it just works in parts.

I work on a Debian4.9-System, the php-file is in `/var/www/html/` (will change this). I suspect, that it is some rights-issue, but I don't know what exactly and how to solve it. How can I give `www-data` (or who?) permission to execute the php module [ARC2](https://github.com/semsol/arc2/) and make a SPARQL request from my [Fuseki 2](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2) Server?

My MWE:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
            include_once("semsol/ARC2.php");
            $config = array (
                'remote_store_endpoint' => 'http://localhost:3030/test/query',
            );
            $store  = ARC2::getRemoteStore($config);
            $query  = 'SELECT * WHERE {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 10';
            $rows   = $store->query($query, 'rows');

            echo "<table>";
            foreach ($rows as $row) {
                print "<tr><td>" .
                $row['s'] . "</td><td>" .
                $row['p'] . "</td><td>" .
                $row['o'] . "</td></tr>" ;
            }
                echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

In console it parses well, in browser it stops at `<html><body>`.

Comment: did you turn on the errors?

Comment: Your foreach is not closed with `}`

Comment: Duplicate, yes. Works if I write the whole path to ARC2 (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12820243/5764123) Thanks!